# How to download private file from s3 using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I have saved a file in amazon s3 bucked as a private file now I want to download this file. I am using amazon s3 PHP component

my download function is as below but I am getting exception [403] Unexpected HTTP status

```
function downloadPrivateFile($bucket, $fileUrl) {
        $obj = new S3($this->keyId, $this->secretKey);
        echo $obj->getObjectInfo($bucket, $fileUrl);
    }
```

Can anyone please help me how to download a private file.

Comment: 403 means "forbidden", so your authentication is most probably wrong.

Comment: I am getting proper url with signature still access denied to generate signed url I am using in built class of sdk @GeraldSchneider